# YouTube API only fetching latest 20,000 videos on a channel

Tags: r, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to get the videoId's of all the videos in a channel.
But when I run the command `list_channel_videos(channel_id = "channel_id", max_results = 5000)` using package **tuber** in **R**, only the latest 20,000 videos are returned.

Is there any workaround the 20,000 limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this is a new server-side limit coming from YouTube. There is an open issue in the youtube-dl repo on Github regarding the same: https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/26092. I haven't seen/thought of a workaround yet.